# Eliminating various backgrounds from image and segmenting object?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-cvst

Let say I have this input image, with any number of boxes. I want to segment out these boxes, so I can eventually extract them out.
input image:

[image]

The background could anything that is continuous, like a painted wall, wooden table, carpet.
My idea was that the gradient would be the same throughout the background, and with a constant gradient. I could turn where the gradient is about the same, into zero's in the image.

Through edge detection, I would dilate and fill the regions where edges detected. Essentially my goal is to make a blob of the areas where the boxes are. Having the blobs, I would know the exact location of the boxes, thus being able to crop out the boxes from the input image.
So in this case, I should be able to have four blobs, and then I would be able to crop out four images from the input image.

This is how far I got:
segmented image:

[image]

```
query = imread('AllFour.jpg');
gray = rgb2gray(query);
[~, threshold] = edge(gray, 'sobel');
weightedFactor = 1.5;
BWs = edge(gray,'roberts');
%figure, imshow(BWs), title('binary gradient mask');

se90 = strel('disk', 30);
se0 = strel('square', 3);

BWsdil = imdilate(BWs, [se90]);
%figure, imshow(BWsdil), title('dilated gradient mask');

BWdfill = imfill(BWsdil, 'holes');
figure, imshow(BWdfill);
title('binary image with filled holes');
```

Comment: I am not even getting anywhere by using the magnitude of the gradients by using `imgradient(query)`. I normalized the magnitude. I should be able to seperate the objects from the foreground if the background is continuous. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a very interesting problem!  Here's my solution in an attempt to solve this problem for you.  This is assuming that the background has the same colour distribution throughout.  First, transform your image from RGB to the HSV colour space with [`rgb2hsv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html).  The HSV colour space is an ideal transform for analyzing colours.  After this, I would look at the saturation and value planes.  Saturation is concerned with how "pure" the colour is, while value is the intensity or brightness of the colour itself.  If you take a look at the saturation and value planes for the image, this is what is shown:

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SGVm.jpg');
out = rgb2hsv(im);
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
imshow(out(:,:,2));
subplot(2,1,2);
imshow(out(:,:,3));
```

This is what I get:

[image]

By taking a look at some locations in the gray background, it looks like the majority of the saturation are less than 0.2 as well as the elements in the value plane are greater than 0.3.  As such, we want to find the **opposite** of those pixels to get our objects.  As such, we find those pixels whose saturation is greater than 0.2 **or** those pixels with a value that is less than 0.3:

```
seg = out(:,:,2) > 0.2 | out(:,:,3) < 0.3;
```

This is what we get:

[image]

Almost there!  There are some spurious single pixels, so I'm going to perform an opening with [`imopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) with a line structuring element.

After this, I'll perform a dilation with [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) to close any gaps, then use [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) with the `'holes'` option to fill in the gaps, then use erosion with [`imerode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) to shrink the shapes back to their original form.  As such:

```
se = strel('line', 3, 90);
pre = imopen(seg, c);
se = strel('square', 20);
pre2 = imdilate(pre, se);
pre3 = imfill(pre2, 'holes');
final = imerode(pre3, se);
figure;
imshow(final);
```

`final` contains the segmented image with the 4 candy boxes. This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.
I will look into more indepth. I noticed that you did not take a edge detection approach? I was thinking about using a hough transform after detecting the edges to join the edges. I havn't implemented that yet- but what do you think?

Comment: 1. Why did you decide to use a vertical line stucturing element to open up the pixels, why not horizontal?

Comment: @Kayla - Hi!  I didn't take the edge detection approach because the previous poster already did so.  I decided to try and be unique and do this completely using colour information and morphology.  Hough Transform could work, then you can apply a filling operation to get the right result.  You'll have to try it because I'm not sure what will happen.  There seems to be a flash towards the right of the image that may mess up your results

Comment: @Kayla - The choice between a vertical or horizontal line was quite arbitrary.  You can use either a horizontal or vertical line to eliminate single dots in the image.  You can use either one to get your results.  I chose vertical arbitrarily.

Comment: I could not end up using this method. My goal was to segment the query image and use knn to match SURF features. Turns out there is too much variations when you query other images due to lighting and shadowing. Maybe I could of used to some noise filter to get of that lighting effect

Comment: Perhaps use adaptive thresholding or homomorphic filtering to eliminate this variance.  For adaptive thresholding, here's a great algorithm: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220494200_Adaptive_Thresholding_using_the_Integral_Image/links/00b7d52b9d30a2108d000000 .  I use it when I have to "scan" documents in when I don't have a scanner.  I take a picture off my mobile phone, then run it through this algorithm to get a great picture.

Answer (score 2):

Try resizing the image. When you make it smaller, it would be easier to join edges. I tried what's shown below. You might have to tune it depending on the nature of the background.

```
close all;
clear all;

im = imread('1SGVm.jpg');
small = imresize(im, .25); % resize
grad = (double(imdilate(small, ones(3))) - double(small)); % extract edges
gradSum = sum(grad, 3);
bw = edge(gradSum, 'Canny');
joined = imdilate(bw, ones(3)); % join edges
filled = imfill(joined, 'holes');
filled = imerode(filled, ones(3));
imshow(label2rgb(bwlabel(filled))) % label the regions and show
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. What would I have to tune and why?

Comment: What does `gradSum = sum(grad, 3);` do?

Comment: Sometimes you may have to try different structuring elements to join edges. Here it was enough to use rectangular element of size 3. sum(grad, 3) sums the pixels of all three channels of grad. Rather than converting from RGB to gray, I sum the pixels, because then all channels are weighted equally, so I won't lose edge information in channels.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of MATLAB, try the [Color Thresholder](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2014/04/25/color-thresholder-app-in-r2014a/) app in the image processing toolbox.  It lets you interactively play with different color spaces, to see which one can give you the best segmentation.

Answer (score -1):

If your candy covers are fixed or you know all the covers that are coming into the scene then **Template matching** is best for this. As it is independent of the background in the image.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: -1.  From the context of the question, there is no template and the template is not known.  I believe this is general object extraction with any number of objects on a uniform background.  You have also placed documentation to OpenCV when this is a MATLAB question.  Please read the tags carefully before posting an answer.